# Change the input size in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have trained a fully convolutional neural network with Keras. I have used the Functional API and have defined the input layer as `Input(shape=(128,128,3))`, corresponding to the size of the images in my training set.

However, I want to use the trained model on images of **variable** sizes (which should be ok because the network is fully convolutional). To do this, I need to change my input layer to `Input(shape=(None,None,3))`. The obvious way to solve the problem would have been to train my model directly with an input shape of `(None,None,3)` but I use a custom loss function where I need to specify the size of my training images.

I have tried to define a new input layer and assign it to my model like this :

```
from keras.engine import InputLayer

input_layer = InputLayer(input_shape=(None, None, 3), name="input")
model.layers[0] = input_layer
```

This actually changes the size of the input layers accordingly but the following layers still expect `(128,128,filters)` inputs.

Is there a way to change all of the inputs values at once ?

Answer (score 8):

Create a new model, exactly the same, except for new input shape; and tranfer weights:

```
newModel.set_weights(oldModel.get_weights())
```

If anything goes wrong, then it might not be fully convolutional (ex: contains a Flatten layer).

Comment: is this really the only solution? isn't it possible to change the expected input size of an existing model?

Comment: Pytorch is faster, good for "eager modes", but hugely lacks model manipulating capabilities....

Comment: we're getting off topic here but what type of manipulating do you find lacking? i thought pretty much everything was more flexible in pytorch.

Comment: You can't get a PyTorch model, split in half, use only a part of it, enumerate all its layers, join parts of other models. You need to rewrite everything.

Comment: @DanielMöller, can you take a look at my question at this link?  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55737/changing-dims-of-keras-input-layer-to-match-pre-trained-weights-for-a-cnn

Comment: @DanielMöller, I tried this and it told me that I could not leave the channels dimension as `None`.  But I concatenate 11 images instead of 3 images in the original CNN that has trained weights, so I have to change the channels dim from 9 to 33.

Comment: Changing the channels is impossible. It will need a totally different weights matrix, which you will need to train.

Comment: Layer weight shape (3, 8) not compatible with provided weight shape (2, 8). Old: `model = keras.Sequential(keras.layers.LSTM(units=2, input_shape=(2, 2))
)`, New: `model2 = keras.Sequential(keras.layers.LSTM(units=2, input_shape=(2, 3))
)`.

Comment: @JokeHuang, you cannot change the number of units, the question is about fully convolutional models, to change the "size" of the images, not the number of channels. With LSTMs, you can only change the "length/steps" of the sequences, not the units/features.